# Applet painting over JMenu

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a class extending `JFrame` that contains a `JMenuBar` and a few components, the innermost of which displays an `Applet`. When the applet is loaded and I click on one of the menus on the menu bar, I find that the dropdown portion of the menu is hidden beneath the applet.

Here is a picture to illustrate this:

[image: Applet painting over a menu.]

I suspect that the reason why this is happening is because I am mixing the heavyweight `Applet` component with the lightweight everything else. I've looked into this and it seems that from the resources that I've visited, the answers converge to: don't do it or validate the top-level container.

I've tried the latter with no avail. Here is my code (it's in a multi-threaded environment):

```
public void add(final Applet applet) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            centerCenterPanel.add(applet);
            centerCenterPanel.revalidate();
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(applet).validate();
        }
    });
}
```

Not doing it is not an option because the applet that I am loading is not mine in the sense that I did not create it, I am merely loading it. Bottom line is that I cannot make the applet a `JApplet` or some other component. However, wrapping it may be a possibility.

Has anybody got any suggestions as to how I could fix this overlapping?

Comment: search for mixing heavyweight with lightweight in AWT/Swing

Comment: I've already looked at that, and according to it I shouldn't even have to worry about it since Java 7, which I'm using. However, I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. These two lines do the trick.

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```